# Получить номер строки в listwidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qlistwidget

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на `pushButton2` программа находила строку в `listWidget` с текстом, который содержится в `lineEdit2` и выводила номер этой строки вместе с её текстом. Как это можно реализовать?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(517, 279)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, 2, 379, 276))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(391, 43, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(391, 10, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Enter text") 
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(391, 80, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit2.setPlaceholderText("Enter text to find")
        self.lineEdit2.setObjectName("lineEdit2")
        self.pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(391, 110, 110, 23))
        self.pushButton2.setObjectName("pushButton2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add"))
        self.pushButton2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Print row"))

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add) #добавить item в listwidget

    def add(self):
        text = (self.lineEdit.text()).strip()
        if text:
            self.listWidget.addItem(text)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QList<QListWidgetItem *> QListWidget::**findItems**(const QString &text, Qt::MatchFlags flags) const
>
> Находит элементы, текст которых соответствует тексту строки, используя заданные флаги.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(517, 279)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, 2, 379, 276))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(391, 43, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(391, 10, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Enter text") 
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(391, 80, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit2.setPlaceholderText("Enter text to find")
        self.lineEdit2.setObjectName("lineEdit2")
        self.pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(391, 110, 110, 23))
        self.pushButton2.setObjectName("pushButton2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add"))
        self.pushButton2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Print row"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add)                
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.printRow)                             # +++

    def add(self):
        text = (self.lineEdit.text()).strip()
        if text:
            self.listWidget.addItem(text)
            
    def printRow(self):
        if not self.lineEdit2.text():
            return
        if not self.listWidget.count():
            return
            
        text = self.lineEdit2.text()     
        all_items = self.listWidget.findItems(text, QtCore.Qt.MatchRegExp)
        for item in all_items:
            print(f'row = {self.listWidget.row(item)}, text = {item.text()}')           
            

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]